# getting the value of dropdown menu's and displaying choice using JS

Tags: javascript, html

Once the user chooses which flavour they want, I want to be able to display a message on the webpage with the choices they have made from the drop-downs after the submit button is clicked. Here is what I have so far:

```
<select name="flavour1" required>
    <option value="">Please select a Flavour!</option>
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="strawberry">Strawberry</option>
    <option value="lemon">lemon</option>
    <option value="pear">Pear</option>
    <option value="cola">Cola</option>
    <option value="lime">Lime</option>
</select>

<select name="flavour2" required>
    <option value="">Please select a Flavour!</option>
    <option value="noflavour">No More Flavours!</option>
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="strawberry">Strawberry</option>
    <option value="lemon">lemon</option>
    <option value="pear">Pear</option>
    <option value="cola">Cola</option>
    <option value="lime">Lime</option>
</select>

      <input type="submit" value="Get your Flavour!!" onclick="getFlavour()">
```

JavaScript to attempt to display message into element with id: "postFlavour"

```
function getFlavour(){
        var flavour1 = getElementById("flavour1").value;
        var flavour2 = getElementById("flavour1").value;

        document.getElementById("postFlavour").innerHTML = "Congratulations, here are your chosen flavours: "+flavour1+", "+flavour2;
    }
```

Comment: If you're using a `<form>` you're submitting the form when you click the button. You need to prevent the submission. Add `return false;` to the end of the function.

Comment: ...also, you have `getElementById("flavour1").value` twice. The second should be `"flavour2"`

Comment: ...and your `select` elements don't have an ID, just a NAME. So you need to add an ID to select using `getElementById()`.

Comment: ...and IE doesn't like the `.value` attribute on `<select>` elements, so store each `select` element in a variable and do `var falvour1 = sel1.options[sel1.selectedIndex];`

Comment: is this what you mean cookie..

Comment: Yes, as long as you added an ID attribute to both `select` elements as well. `<select name="flavour2" id="flavour2" required>`

Comment: yes I have done all that but it still isn't displaying the message..

Comment: What/where is the element with the ID `postFlavour`?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFlavour(){
    var sel1 = getElementById("flavour1");
    var sel2 = getElementById("flavour2");

    var flavour1 = sel1.options[sel1.selectedIndex];
    var flavour2 = sel2.options[sel2.selectedIndex];

    document.getElementById("postFlavour").innerHTML = "Congratulation, here are your chosen flavours: "+flavour1+", "+flavour2;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: ok I have the message now but heres what it says:

Congratulation, here are your chosen flavours: [object HTMLOptionElement], [object HTMLOptionElement]